# Unsigned int into a char array. Alternative to itoa?

Tags: c++, char, arrays, unsigned-integer, itoa

I have a question about unsigned ints.
I would like to convert my unsigned int into a char array. For that I use itoa. The problem is that itoa works properly with ints, but not with unsigned int (the unsigned int is treaded as a normal int).
How should I convert unsigned int into a char array?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: There is `std::to_string` in `<string>` in C++11.

Comment: @johnchen902 Worth noting: GCC as of current (4.9.2) and a couple of versions before lacks `std::to_string` (known library defect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is a common approach:

```
#include<sstream>
...

std::ostringstream oss;
unsigned int u = 598106;

oss << u;
printf("char array=%s\n", oss.str().c_str());
```

**Update** since C++11 there is [std::to_string()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) method -:

```
 #include<string>
 ...
 unsigned int u = 0xffffffff;
 std::string s = std::to_string(u);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply Make your own function like this one :

[Code Link On Ideone using OWN Function](http://ideone.com/AzPe7O)

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdio>
    #include<cmath>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        unsigned int num,l,i;

        cin>>num;
        l = log10(num) + 1; // Length of number like if num=123456 then l=6.
        char* ans = new char[l+1];
        i = l-1;

        while(num>0 && i>=0)
        {
            ans[i--]=(char)(num%10+48);
            num/=10;
        }
        ans[l]='\0';
        cout<<ans<<endl;

        delete ans;

        return 0;
    }
```

You can also use the `sprintf` function (standard in C)

```
sprintf(str, "%d", a); //a is your number ,str will contain your number as string
```

[Code Link On Ideone Using Sprintf](http://ideone.com/iKfH7N)

Comment: Not reinvent the wheel, use well documented standard library solutions instead, like `std::stringstream` or `std::to_string()`.

Comment: i am not trying to reinvent the wheel. i just told what i know(what i use in my programming ).. more importantly. this is not wrong. so there is no need of down vote for that .. anyways thanks for that :) !

Comment: Well, is not wrong, but the key concept (Use libraries vs reimplement everithing) is wrong. But, well you are right and that not implies a votedown. Sorry. The 8-min period passed and I can't undo the downvote :(

Comment: No. there is no need for upvoting now!. i don't know C++ 11. i only know c++ 4.3.2 so you are right !

Comment: @Shashank_Jain - +1 i agree with you for not using GMP library they don't allow that in programming contests !

Comment: worked for `unsigned int` range, is there a way to improve it and convert bigger values for `unsigned long` ?